# Subscription not being fired within app.component.ts after login

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, observable

I need to understand why my observable isn't being fired after a successfull login, this is what I have so far:

app.component.ts

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    const sub = this.authService.CurrentUser.pipe(
        concatMap(user => {
            if(user) {
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                this.service.getParticipants(user.id);
            }

            return throwError('Error');
        }),
    ).subscribe();
}
```

service.ts

```
public GetParticipants(id: string): Observable<Participant> {
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/participant/GetParticipants?enterpriseId=${enterpriseId}`)
            .pipe(
                map(p => Participant.fromJsonToParticipant(p))
            );
    }
```

auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {    
    private currentUser = new BehaviorSubject<Participant | null>(null);
    public currentUser$ = this.currentUser.asObservable();

    public get CurrentUser(): Observable<Participant | null> {
        return this.currentUser.asObservable();
    }

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        const storageUser = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser');
        const userJson = storageUser ? JSON.parse(storageUser) : null;
        const user = storageUser ? Participant.fromJsonToParticipant(userJson) : null;

        if(user) {
            this.currentUser.next(user);
        }
    }

    public login(username: string, password: string): void {
        // Login logic

        sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(participant));
        this.currentUser.next(user);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUser.next(null);
    }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
                (m) => m.DashboardModule
            ),
        canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard],
        canLoad: [CanLoadAuthGuard],
    }];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.component subscription is only fired at startup but after I perform the login, the subscription isn't fired again and I don't have a clue why this is happening. It's like the subscription was closed after the login

Comment: I guess the `throwError` cancels the subscription. Remove it and test again.

Comment: Also move the code from the concatMap's inner function to subscribe.

Comment: What do you want to do with `this.service.getParticipants(user.id)`? You're not using its value anywhere.

Comment: I’m Saving in session the current logged user

Comment: @Juanma But `this.service.getParticipants(user.id)` returns an http request as observable, it's not saving the user in the sessionStorage. I don't understand what calling `this.service.getParticipants(user.id)` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you changed the concatMap to a tap and get rid of the error?

```
    const sub = this.authService.CurrentUser.pipe(
        tap(user => {
            if(user) {
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                this.service.getParticipants(user.id);
            }
        }),
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Note that `this.service.getParticipants(user.id)` returns an observable. So just calling the function in a `tap` has probably not the desired effect.

Comment: I’ve tried the tap thing and it works fine and also removed throw error. But is that ok? I mean, is ok to invoke multiple http service request within a tap?